# Minimal Atmel ATSAM4LC4A parts requirement

Tags: atmel, development

I want to make myself a developmet board with that chip.

http://www.atmel.co.il/devices/ATSAM4LC4A.aspx

And I would like to get a schematic or anything that will help building a development board.

Comment: It's all laid out in the datasheet like dinner on the ground. This is too broad, and give me the schematic questions are not looked up fondly.

Comment: insufficient preliminary research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application note: Atmel AT01777

And also: [Production files](http://www.atmel.com/tools/sam4l-ek.aspx?tab=documents)